# What does "they" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, subjects

I don't understand the pronoun "they" and the subject of "are" in the following sentence.

> Silver prices yesterday jumped 13% to an eight-year high after some online investors suggested dumping money into silver would hurt big banks they believe are artificially suppressing prices.

Can I interpret "big banks ~" to the following?
big banks (that) online investors believe (that) bankers are artificially suppressing prices.

Comment: They (some online investors) believe that big banks are suppressing prices.

Comment: “They” refers to “some online bankers”. Within the bracketed relative clause in “big banks [they believe ____ are artificially suppressing prices]” gap represents the covert presence of the relativised element functioning as subject of the embedded “are” clause, and is related directly to the nominal “big banks”. We understand that some online investors believe that big banks are artificially suppressing prices.

Comment: No, "they" doesn't refer to "online bankers." It refers to "some online investors."

Comment: Correction: "some online bankers" should read "some online investors".